# BeautifulSoup: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.data.jma.go.jp/obd/stats/etrn/view/monthly_s3_en.php?block_no=47401&view=1'
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()        
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find_all('table', class_='data2_s')
rows = table.find_all('tr')
print rows

 rows = table.find_all('tr')
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

I want to grasp the table into a CSV file.
How to go ahead?

This is the table:

```
[<table class="data2_s"><caption class="m">WAKKANAI\xa0\xa0\xa0WMO Station ID:47401\xa0Lat\xa045<sup>o</sup>24.9'N\xa0\xa0Lon\xa0141<sup>o</sup>40.7'E</caption><tr><th scope="col">Year</th><th scope="col">Jan</th><th scope="col">Feb</th><th scope="col">Mar</th><th scope="col">Apr</th><th scope="col">May</th><th scope="col">Jun</th><th scope="col">Jul</th><th scope="col">Aug</th><th scope="col">Sep</th><th scope="col">Oct</th><th scope="col">Nov</th><th scope="col">Dec</th><th scope="col">Annual</th></tr><tr class="mtx" style="text-align:right;"><td style="text-align:center">1938</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">-5.2</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">-4.9</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">-0.6</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">4.7</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">9.5</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">11.6</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">17.9</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">22.2</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">16.5</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">10.7</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">3.3</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">-4.7</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">6.8</td></tr>\n<tr class="mtx" style="text-align:right;"><td style="text-align:center">1939</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">-7.5</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">-6.6</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">-1.4</td><td]
```

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is... "Did not work" isn't enough info

Comment: @Totem Hey I got AttributeError as mentioned in question.

Comment: Ok, I think that error is telling you what's wrong.. the ResultSet is more than likely contained in 'rows'...

Comment: @Totem So, how can i convert that table into CSV? I post the table as resulted from `soup.find_all('table', class_='data2_s')'

Comment: Not entirely sure, but try rows = table[0].find_all('tr') instead

Comment: @Totem yes, that resulted 'no error'. So then how to convert that table into csv?

Comment: when you want a single tag use *find* not *find_all*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
rows = table[0].find_all('tr')
```

Since `find_all` appears to return a Python `list`, you were trying to call `find_all` on a `list`, which doesn't have such a method.

To get your resulting list(`rows`) into CSV format.. well, that depends. If you just want it on screen, you could do:

```
','.join(rows)
```

If you wanted it in a file, you would need to open a file and write the above line to it. But there are also Python modules that deal with creating CSV content. It's a different question really.

Comment: you might be interested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917958/convert-html-into-csv

Comment: you might be interested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917958/convert-html-into-csv

Comment: You should use `find` when you want a single tag, find_all returns all matches