# Convert HTML into CSV

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I want to convert a HTML table as obtained from the script below into a CSV file, but  got type error as follows:

> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, Tag found

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.data.jma.go.jp/obd/stats/etrn/view/monthly_s3_en.php?block_no=47401&view=1'
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()        
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find_all('table', class_='data2_s')
rows = table[0].find_all('tr')
```

How is the easiest way to convert it into a CSV file?
I tried as:

```
fo = open('fo.txt','w')
for r in rows:
    fo.write(str(r.txt) + '\n')
fo.close()
```

but it wrote 'none'

The HTML is like this:

```
<table class="data2_s"><caption class="m">WAKKANAIÂ Â Â WMO Station ID:47401Â LatÂ 45<sup>o</sup>24.9'NÂ Â LonÂ 141<sup>o</sup>40.7'E</caption><tr><th scope="col">Year</th><th scope="col">Jan</th><th scope="col">Feb</th><th scope="col">Mar</th><th scope="col">Apr</th><th scope="col">May</th><th scope="col">Jun</th><th scope="col">Jul</th><th scope="col">Aug</th><th scope="col">Sep</th><th scope="col">Oct</th><th scope="col">Nov</th><th scope="col">Dec</th><th scope="col">Annual</th></tr><tr class="mtx" style="text-align:right;"><td style="text-align:center">1938</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">-5.2</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">-4.9</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">-0.6</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">4.7</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">9.5</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">11.6</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">17.9</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">22.2</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">16.5</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">10.7</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">3.3</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">-4.7</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">6.8</td></tr>
<tr class="mtx" style="text-align:right;"><td style="text-align:center">1939</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">-7.5</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">-6.6</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">-1.4</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">4.0</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">7.5</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">13.0</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">17.4</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">20.0</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">17.4</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">9.7</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">3.0</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">-2.5</td><td class="data_0_0_0_0">6.2</td></tr>
```

Comment: maybe print ','.join(str(t) for t in rows), but you still end up with a lot of html tags and such included in the rows, unless that's ok.

Comment: perhaps something more like csv_rows = ','.join([r.text for r in rows])

Comment: @Totem could you see my edits?

Comment: @jean, please add sample HTML that you're using as part of the question?

Comment: Apart from the suggestions by others, you should also change your output file to `fo.csv`.

Comment: @ffledgling yes, I have posted html

Comment: @Repiklis It is still 'None'

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a job for the csv lib, getting each td inside each row and extracting the text, it will handle where there are missing values in each row:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import csv

url = 'http://www.data.jma.go.jp/obd/stats/etrn/view/monthly_s3_en.php?block_no=47401&view=1'
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.select_one("table.data2_s")
# python3 just use th.text
headers = [th.text.encode("utf-8") for th in table.select("tr th")]

with open("out.csv", "w") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    wr.writerow(headers)
    wr.writerows([[td.text.encode("utf-8") for td in row.find_all("td")] for row in table.select("tr + tr")])
```

Which matches the table exactly as you see on the page:

```
:~$ cat out.csv
Year,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,Annual
1938,-5.2,-4.9,-0.6,4.7,9.5,11.6,17.9,22.2,16.5,10.7,3.3,-4.7,6.8
1939,-7.5,-6.6,-1.4,4.0,7.5,13.0,17.4,20.0,17.4,9.7,3.0,-2.5,6.2
1940,-6.0,-5.7,-0.5,3.5,8.5,11.0,16.6,19.7,15.6,10.4,3.7,-1.0,6.3
1941,-6.5,-5.8,-2.6,3.6,8.1,11.4,12.7,16.5,16.0,10.0,4.0,-2.9,5.4
1942,-7.8,-8.2,-0.8,3.5,7.1,12.0,17.4,18.4,15.7,10.5,2.5,-2.9,5.6
1943,-4.1,-6.1,-1.1,3.5,6.9,12.9,19.3,21.5,17.5,11.7,1.2,-3.6,6.6
1944,-7.7,-7.9,-2.2,1.7,8.9,13.7,19.0,21.3,16.6,10.8,1.3,-6.0,5.8
1945,-7.8,-6.9,-1.8,3.9,5.5,11.0,13.6,18.7,16.8,11.0,3.9,-4.8,5.3
1946,-6.5,-6.0,-3.3,4.5,7.6,14.9,18.2,22.2,16.9,11.5,4.4,-2.5,6.8
1947,-4.9,-5.5,-2.3,3.7,9.0,11.2,17.1,19.3,15.1,10.6,2.4,-4.6,5.9
1948,-2.7,-4.4,-0.2,6.0,10.7,12.2,16.2,22.0,16.9,11.1,4.2,-0.6,7.6
1949,-2.6,-2.8,-3.4,2.0,9.4,11.8,16.9,20.8,17.8,10.8,3.1,-3.8,6.7
1950,-5.7,-4.8,-1.3,4.0,9.2,14.6,19.3,22.6,16.8,9.0,3.0,-2.9,7.0
1951,-6.7,-6.5,-2.2,3.7,9.5,12.3,16.7,22.3,15.6,10.1,3.7,-0.3,6.5
1952,-5.7,-7.1,-2.4,3.8,8.3,13.1,16.4,19.7,17.0,11.3,0.9,-7.1,5.7
1953,-7.7,-7.3,-0.9,3.6,6.9,11.1,16.8,19.2,17.6,11.2,-0.6,-2.6,5.6
1954,-6.7,-4.1,-2.5,4.0,7.5,11.0,13.7,17.0,17.2,9.5,3.2,-1.8,5.7
1955,-6.4,-4.8,-1.3,4.7,7.0,12.7,20.3,19.5,15.5,10.6,3.6,-0.4,6.8
1956,-6.1,-4.6,-2.0,5.1,10.8,11.2,13.8,16.3,17.2,12.3,2.8,-2.6,6.2
1957,-3.9,-5.5,-2.9,4.4,9.3,10.9,17.1,18.2,15.5,11.1,5.4,-1.1,6.5
1958,-4.9,-4.9,-2.3,4.4,8.5,12.6,17.5,18.3,16.8,10.6,4.5,-0.5,6.7
1959,-7.3,-2.8,0.8,6.4,9.4,12.7,17.1,18.5,16.2,11.6,2.9,-3.9,6.8
1960,-7.2,-5.2,-1.4,3.5,7.7,10.8,15.9,20.8,18.1,9.7,3.3,-3.9,6.0
1961,-7.7,-5.3,-1.4,5.5,8.7,14.7,19.5,20.0,18.9,10.4,4.1,-1.3,7.2
1962,-4.2,-5.4,-2.5,6.7,10.0,12.9,16.8,17.7,16.6,9.9,2.6,-1.5,6.6
1963,-3.6,-3.7,0.1,5.0,10.4,12.4,16.8,17.1,15.6,10.7,4.3,-1.7,7.0
1964,-4.5,-7.7,-1.3,3.7,9.9,11.9,15.3,17.7,14.9,10.0,3.6,-1.9,6.0
1965,-4.1,-5.7,-2.8,3.2,9.1,13.3,15.2,18.8,15.8,11.4,2.1,-2.6,6.1
1966,-5.0,-5.5,-1.0,3.2,8.1,12.2,15.3,17.5,15.4,11.6,4.1,-4.4,6.0
1967,-6.8,-5.9,-0.7,4.5,10.0,11.4,16.4,20.5,15.5,11.0,1.8,-1.5,6.4
1968,-4.2,-4.7,1.9,5.7,8.9,14.5,17.3,18.1,15.9,9.1,5.3,-0.7,7.3
1969,-7.3,-7.5,-2.5,3.9,7.2,10.6,17.0,16.5,16.1,9.4,2.2,-5.4,5.0
1970,-6.6,-6.0,-4.2,4.6,10.4,12.9,17.4,19.2,16.8,10.5,4.3,-3.3,6.3
1971,-6.3,-6.4,-1.7,4.1,7.6,11.6,15.8,17.2,15.2,11.5,3.4,-2.2,5.8
1972,-5.3,-5.0,-0.6,5.9,9.4,12.8,16.8,20.4,15.7,10.9,1.9,-1.4,6.8
1973,-4.2,-5.3,-2.9,4.2,8.4,12.8,17.0,20.9,17.1,10.4,3.5,-1.9,6.7
1974,-2.6,-4.6,-2.1,4.0,8.4,11.8,16.8,18.8,16.5,10.1,1.9,-5.7,6.1
1975,-4.1,-6.1,-1.5,4.3,8.4,13.7,16.1,20.6,17.3,10.4,3.8,-3.8,6.6
1976,-4.6,-3.5,-1.4,4.0,8.9,11.9,17.5,17.6,15.7,10.2,1.3,-2.0,6.3
1977,-8.3,-7.1,-1.0,3.6,8.0,11.9,18.2,19.1,17.4,11.4,4.5,-1.8,6.3
1978,-6.7,-9.2,-1.6,4.3,9.2,13.5,20.6,21.3,17.4,9.6,3.4,-2.1,6.6
1979,-6.9,-4.5,-2.5,2.7,7.8,13.2,15.8,20.3,16.9,11.3,2.9,-0.1,6.4
1980,-5.4,-7.1,-1.9,1.9,7.8,12.9,15.9,16.5,16.0,10.0,4.3,-0.6,5.9
1981,-5.4,-6.3,-2.6,5.6,8.1,11.8,17.1,18.7,16.0,10.5,0.8,-0.6,6.1
1982,-5.6,-5.3,-0.6,3.7,9.0,11.9,16.9,21.0,17.5,11.4,4.3,-1.0,6.9
1983,-4.2,-7.6,-1.9,6.8,8.2,8.5,14.5,18.9,15.8,8.9,4.8,-2.1,5.9
1984,-4.9,-6.6,-3.3,2.9,7.9,15.5,19.5,20.5,16.6,9.2,2.3,-3.6,6.3
1985,-8.7,-4.8,-1.4,4.9,8.6,11.7,16.6,21.1,15.7,10.3,2.7,-4.2,6.0
1986,-7.2,-6.5,-2.4,4.6,8.4,11.2,14.4,19.6,16.8,9.1,2.1,-1.9,5.7
1987,-6.4,-5.6,-1.4,4.2,8.6,12.6,17.5,18.0,16.4,11.1,2.0,-3.1,6.2
1988,-4.8,-6.3,-1.8,4.1,8.0,12.6,14.1,20.4,16.1,10.4,2.0,-1.5,6.1
1989,-2.6,-2.4,0.8,4.0,8.2,10.7,18.4,20.4,16.8,10.8,4.8,-1.3,7.4
1990,-5.7,-2.4,1.4,5.7,9.3,13.4,18.9,20.3,17.1,13.3,6.2,1.2,8.2
1991,-1.6,-3.6,-1.5,4.8,10.1,14.3,16.2,19.0,16.6,11.8,3.5,-2.3,7.3
1992,-3.6,-3.6,-0.4,3.7,8.1,12.1,17.6,18.0,14.9,11.1,3.2,-1.2,6.7
1993,-2.7,-3.3,-0.2,3.1,8.6,10.7,15.6,17.6,16.3,11.1,3.7,-1.6,6.6
1994,-6.1,-2.7,-1.3,4.4,10.0,12.8,17.4,21.7,17.5,11.8,4.3,-2.9,7.2
1995,-4.0,-4.0,-0.8,4.8,11.0,12.7,18.4,19.3,16.3,12.3,5.2,-0.6,7.6
1996,-4.6,-4.5,-1.0,3.5,6.9,12.0,15.9,18.7,16.8,10.4,2.3,-2.4,6.2
1997,-3.0,-3.3,-1.5,4.3,7.3,11.7,17.4,17.2,16.1,10.3,6.4,-0.7,6.9
1998,-6.9,-5.1,0.3,5.3,10.1,12.9,15.5,18.1,17.2,12.5,2.0,-2.4,6.6
1999,-4.1,-5.6,-2.6,4.2,8.4,14.5,16.6,21.0,18.3,11.2,3.8,-1.9,7.0
2000,-4.2,-5.6,-2.1,3.5,9.3,12.8,18.9,21.5,17.7,10.6,1.5,-4.1,6.7
2001,-6.3,-7.7,-2.4,4.7,8.5,13.0,17.4,18.7,15.6,10.8,4.0,-4.2,6.0
2002,-3.6,-1.0,0.5,6.8,11.1,12.1,15.7,17.1,17.0,10.8,2.3,-4.4,7.0
2003,-4.7,-5.6,-0.7,5.3,10.1,13.9,14.3,18.4,16.6,11.3,4.5,-1.4,6.8
2004,-3.9,-3.0,-0.5,4.4,10.6,14.6,16.8,19.7,17.8,11.8,5.9,-2.0,7.7
2005,-4.6,-5.7,-1.0,3.9,7.0,14.3,16.7,21.0,17.9,12.6,4.9,-2.3,7.1
2006,-5.5,-4.7,-0.9,2.1,9.3,11.9,18.4,21.6,17.7,11.0,4.5,-1.8,7.0
2007,-3.7,-3.2,-0.7,3.5,7.6,14.3,16.7,20.4,17.0,10.9,3.0,-1.7,7.0
2008,-6.0,-4.8,0.6,6.0,8.3,11.9,17.9,18.8,17.9,11.5,3.8,-0.4,7.1
2009,-2.4,-4.4,0.0,4.5,10.0,12.3,14.8,18.6,16.9,11.4,3.1,-2.2,6.9
2010,-3.4,-4.9,-1.4,3.5,7.3,15.0,18.1,22.4,18.4,11.4,4.8,-1.1,7.5
2011,-5.1,-2.2,-0.6,4.4,6.5,12.8,17.5 ),21.5,18.3,12.1,4.9,-2.3,7.3
2012,-5.4,-6.4,-2.4,4.6,8.9,12.6,17.2,20.4,19.4,11.8,3.8,-3.0,6.8
2013,-5.8,-5.1,-1.3,4.5,7.2,14.0,18.9,20.2,17.6,11.8,5.5,-0.2,7.3
2014,-5.3,-4.2,-1.2,3.9,8.7,13.9,19.2,20.0,16.7,11.0,4.8,-2.3,7.1
2015,-2.9,-1.7,2.3,5.9,9.9,12.1,17.6,19.0,17.3,10.4,3.7,-0.2,7.8
2016,-5.2,-4.7,0.5,4.3,11.4,12.5,17.4,21.8 ],　,　,　,　,5.2 ]
```

if you want the caption use `table.select_one("caption.m").text`:

```
with open("out.csv", "w") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    wr.writerow([table.select_one("caption.m").text.encode("utf-8")])
    wr.writerow(headers)
    wr.writerows([[td.text.encode("utf-8") for td in row.find_all("td")] 
for row in table.select("tr + tr")])
```

but it might be an idea to use that as the name of the file as opposed to adding it to the csv.

If you really want to do it without the csv, use the same logic with *str.join*:

```
table = soup.select_one("table.data2_s")
headers = [th.text.encode("utf-8") for th in table.select("tr th")]

with open("out.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write(",".join(headers) + "\n")
    f.writelines(",".join([td.text.encode("utf-8") for td in row.find_all("td")]) + "\n" 
                 for row in table.select("tr + tr"))
```

If you want to replace the empty cells with `N/A`:

```
with open("out.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write(",".join(headers) + "\n")
    f.writelines(",".join([td.text.encode("utf-8").strip('\xe3\x80\x80') or "N/A" for td in row.find_all("td")]) + "\n"
                 for row in table.select("tr + tr"))
```

Which will change the last row to:

```
2016,-5.2,-4.7,0.5,4.3,11.4,12.5,17.4,21.8 ],N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,5.2 ]
```

The spaces for missing values are *unicode* [ideographic space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3000/index.htm) characters (*u"\u3000" in python*) which when encoded to utf-8 become and strip, if that leave an empty string then we just use `"N/A"`

```
In [7]: print u"\u3000"
　
In [8]:  u"\u3000".encode("utf-8")
Out[8]: '\xe3\x80\x80'
In [9]:  u"\u3000".encode("utf-8").strip('\xe3\x80\x80')
Out[9]: ''
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `csv` module from Python to do this. You can obviously write more columns if you want, but the idea is that you're writing a `list` to the csv file. There are other options that you can specify in the `writer()` method if you'd like to quote things, escape things, etc.

```
import csv

with open('your_csv_name.csv', 'w') as o:
    w = csv.writer(o)
    # Headers
    w.writerow(['tr_content'])
    # Write the tr text
    for r in rows:
        w.writerow([r])
```

Comment: It's included in the default Python installation, there's no reason not to use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

html = open('test.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='lxml')
#Specify table name which you want to read.
#Example: <table class="queryResults" border="0" cellspacing="1">
table = soup.select_one('table.queryResults')

def get_all_tables(soup):
    return soup.find_all("table")


tbls = get_all_tables(soup)
for i, tablen in enumerate(tbls, start=1):
    print(i)
    print(tablen)

def get_table_headers(table):
    headers = []
    for th in table.find("tr").find_all("th"):
        headers.append(th.text.strip())
    return headers

head = get_table_headers(table)
#print(head)

def get_table_rows(table):    
    rows = []
    for tr in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
        cells = []
        # grab all td tags in this table row
        tds = tr.find_all("td")
        if len(tds) == 0:
            # if no td tags, search for th tags
            # can be found especially in wikipedia tables below the table
            ths = tr.find_all("th")
            for th in ths:
                cells.append(th.text.strip())
        else:
            # use regular td tags
            for td in tds:
                cells.append(td.text.strip())
        rows.append(cells)
    return rows

table_rows = get_table_rows(table)
#print(table_rows)

def save_as_csv(table_name, headers, rows):
    pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=headers).to_csv(f"{table_name}.csv")

save_as_csv("Test_table", head, table_rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way without using `csv` module:

```
fp=open('data.csv','w')
for row in rows[:-1]:   # Removed last row as it has empty cells that gives error which can also be resolved if needed 
      fp.write(row.get_text(',') + '\n')
fp.close()
```

You can directly open data.csv file.

Station details can be get by below command:

```
>>>> table = soup.find_all('table', class_='data2_s')
>>>> print table[0].find_all('caption')[0].get_text().encode('ascii', 'ignore')
WAKKANAI   WMO Station ID:47401 Lat 45o24.9'N  Lon 141o40.7'E
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, great! It works well. By the way  how to get `WAKKANAI WMO Station ID:47401 Lat 45o24.9'N Lon 141o40.7'E` as text string

Comment: thanks, yes, but that's unicode, how to extract text for `WAKKANAI` , `45o24.9'N', and '141o40.7'E' as strings.

Comment: The last row has  data which you are losing by slicing.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes, but in this case w/o csv, how to put blank cells as 'na'?

Comment: You can use `encode` to convert unicode data to text. updated in answer.
Regarding slicing last row, it has some non-numeric character in it such as ']' and '['

Comment: @jean, see the edit, also  `.encode('ascii', 'ignore')` will also lose more data  so not a good idea either.