# need to convert html to csv file using python or shell script

Tags: python, html, mysql, shell, csv

I have a html file and i need to convert this large html file into csv file and then load this csv file into mysql file

can anyone suggest shell/python script to achive this task

Comment: What code have you tried? Generally speaking, questions that don't show an attempt, don't get an answer.

Comment: please give more information. but this is similar to your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917958/convert-html-into-csv

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may give you an idea for the task: html to csv. [Convert HTML into CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917958/convert-html-into-csv). For the task load csv to mysql, please check this: [Load CSV data into MySQL in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154633/load-csv-data-into-mysql-in-python)