# Convert inner tbody html content to json

Tags: python, web-scraping, iframe, html-tbody

I'm trying to get web data from a website, and I only need to grab inner html data from a tbody class and convert it into json for better control as well as to save the data into a file later on. I've only managed to read each element by using find_element(By.XPATH) from selenium. Is there any way to read the whole innter html tbody content then parse it to json? requests wont work since it's inside an iframe.
The [website](https://covid19.gov.vn/) and the tbody is the scroll table with title :"Tình hình dịch cả nước", I only want the table minus the title, and the header of the table if possible.
The code for reading an element:

```
browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://covid19.gov.vn/")
time.sleep(3)
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/iframe'))
value=browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/span[4]')
print(value.text)
```

Comment: There is a good answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917958/convert-html-into-csv . It uses BeautifulSoup to extract data from HTML, which is what you probably want to do.

Comment: @AmitaiIrron thank you for your suggestion. But I did find an alternative that's much shorter which I will edit in my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the same endpoint the page does which returns JSON.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://static.pipezero.com/covid/data.json').json()
location_json = r['locations']
df = pd.DataFrame(location_json)
print(df)
```